# How to disable 'No (more) search results' sound

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ gives a beep when no more search results are found (e.g. when pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>).

How can I disable this?

(Always using the latest version, currently 7.9)

Comment: Not possible. See [Sound after an unsuccessful search cannot be disabled · Issue #7950 · notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/7950) for possible workarounds

Comment: Too bad. Even the workaround from that post (using the Windows sound mixer) does not seem to work. If I start Notepad++, then open the mixer, Notepad++ isn't there (even after forcing a sound from it). This seems like a temp fix anyway, if you close Notepadd++ again.